# Boost ASIO - How to perpend header in front of TCP Message

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Here is my code minimized for the purpose of readability.

I was following this guide: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp

`Packet.h`:

```
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_PACKET_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_PACKET_H


#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

class Packet {
public:
    Packet() : body_length_(0)
    {
    }
    enum { max_body_length = 1024 };
    enum { header_length = 8 };
    char header_[header_length];
    const char* data() const;
    char* data();
    size_t length() const;
    const char* body() const;
    char* body();
    size_t body_length() const;
    void body_length(std::size_t new_length);
    bool decode_header();
    void encode_header();
private:
    char data_[header_length + max_body_length];
    size_t body_length_;
};


#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_PACKET_H
```

`Packet.cpp`:

```
#include "Packet.h"

const char *Packet::data() const {
    return data_;
}

char *Packet::data() {
    return data_;
}

size_t Packet::length() const {
    return header_length + body_length_;
}

const char *Packet::body() const {
    return data_ + header_length;
}

char *Packet::body() {
    return data_ + header_length;
}

size_t Packet::body_length() const {
    return body_length_;
}

void Packet::body_length(std::size_t new_length) {
    body_length_ = new_length;
    if (body_length_ > max_body_length)
        body_length_ = max_body_length;
}

bool Packet::decode_header() {
    char header[header_length + 1] = "";
    std::strncat(header, data_, header_length);
    body_length_ = std::atoi(header);
    if (body_length_ > max_body_length)
    {
        body_length_ = 0;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Packet::encode_header() {
    char header[header_length + 1] = "";
    std::sprintf(header, "%4d", static_cast<int>(body_length_));
    std::memcpy(data_, header, header_length);
}
```

`ServerOpcode.h`:

```
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_SERVEROPCODE_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_SERVEROPCODE_H

#include <cstdint>

enum ServerOpcode : uint16_t{
    SMSG_AUTH_CONNECTION_RESPONSE                    = 0x001,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE                      = 0x002,
};

#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_SERVEROPCODE_H
```

So I would like to modify `encode_header()` to set a `ServerOpcode` as a packet header. I was trying this but it's not working:

```
void Packet::encode_header(ServerOpcode serverOpcode) {
    char header[header_length + 1] = "";
    std::strcat(header, static_cast<char>(serverOpcode));
    std::memcpy(data_, header, header_length);
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I make encode header prepend the `ServerOpcode`? Where is my mistake how can I fix it?
2. How can I decode an incoming message header than with `decode_header()`?

Comment: I suspect a lot of your problems, and a lot of your complexity, are due to reinvented wheels. You're using boost asio, but not even a basic class like `std::string`. You use `std::sprintf` instead of just `std::to_string`. `std::atoi` instead of `std::stoi`.

Comment: I agree with you on this. Can you please make an answer with those changes ?